# Why is my SwiftUI custom view not updated correctly?

Tags: view, swiftui, state

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["red", "blue", "green"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                ItemView(str: items[idx])
            }
            Button("Replace items") {
                items = [ "pig", "dog", "horse" ]
            }
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 150)
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @State var itemstr = ""
    let str: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(str)
            TextField("New: "+str, text: $itemstr)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I see happen:
[image: Initial screen]

Type in some text.

[image: after I type in some text]

Now press the "Replace Items" button.

[image: press button to change underlying state]

Now you can see that the TextField @State
and the "str" label data are not consistent.
"pig" is from the refreshed view and "rreedd" is from the old copy of the view.

Backspace over the text to confirm the initial value is also inconsistent.

[image: backspace over the text to see the TextField initial value.]

It looks like the ItemView custom view is being reconstructed with new initializer parameters (str) but using the old state (itemstr).

My real problem is more complicated than this.  But it involves subviews created with ForEach and the ForEach not being re-iterated the way I expect when the model data changes.

I'm not sure if this is a SwiftUI bug or not because I don't deeply understand the algorithm that SwiftUI uses to propagate view changes.

It seems like it creates a new view, compares the internal state of the new view with the internal state of the old view, and then decides whether to recalculate children and use the new view or whether to stick with the old view.  But I've never seen that spelled out in official docs.

Comment: Maybe use `@Binding` inside `ItemView` instead of `@State`?

Comment: @aheze, you could bind directly, but this approach is typically used when the child view wants to maintain its "unsaved" state and not update the parent directly

Comment: @NewDev ah I see, nice answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

In SwiftUI views are initialized pretty regularly (whenever their parent re-computes its `body`), and it's the state the determines whether the view has actually changed (which means that it too would need to, in turn, recompute its own `body`).

So, when you declare `@State var itemstr = ""`, you're giving that state property an *initial* value of `""`, but then the view maintains its state between initializations.

---

How do you reset the state then?

In your example, I think, it's the `ItemView` that would want to reset its state whenever `str` changes. You'd need to do this explicitly with `onChange`:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    @State var itemstr = ""
    let str: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(str)
            TextField("New: "+str, text: $itemstr)
        }
        .onChange(of: str, perform: { _ in
            itemstr = "" // reset whenever str changes
        })
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, though not necessarily fitting with this example, the parent can inform SwiftUI that its body, despite the view structure looking unchanged, has actually completely changed and that the state should be reset.

In this case, you can is the `.id` view modifier and supply `items[idx]` as the `id` for each item - meaning that when `items[idx]` changes that means that the view hierarchy under it has also changed.

With this approach, you'd only update the parent and can leave `ItemView` as-is:

```
ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
    ItemView(str: items[idx])
       .id(items[idx])
}
```